# Linux distribution for Mail server

Tags: email-server, linux

Do you know linux distribution for mail server?
Im looking something like complex management mail server: mailserver, gui, AV, antispam, web stats + spam stats.

I know i can install pf/exim+webmin but is there complete distribution that has everything i want just after install?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also consider taking a look at SME Server, very flexible with a fairly good range of additions (different webmails, utilities, etc.) which can be installed on top of the base server.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Zimbra community version](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing_zimbra_collaboration_suite_on_ubuntu) & you can install clamAV etc.

Comment: Are there any email/spam stats? And why do you prefer Zimbra?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a hard time finding a distribution dedicated exclusively to e-Mail, as there's not much point when you can simply install the software on top of any distribution.

[QMAIL Toaster](http://www.qmailtoaster.com/) is a software collection meeting your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at http://deeproot.in/deepofix

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [iRedMail OS](http://www.iredmail.org/iredos/0.6.0/)